# Modify shiny datatable search

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I need to change the search input that Shiny displays by default in the browser when the app renders a datatable.
The search input finds the data in the datatable and displays the corresponding information filtering by the user's input.
The problem is that Shiny implements that by default.

I want to implement an input like the search, but instead of filter the data I want the pagination to show the page that the users write in the input.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick solution see below. I hide the current functionality and implement a new one on top.

```
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      # hides the default search functionality
      tags$style(
        HTML(".dataTables_filter, .dataTables_info { display: none; }")
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(10, 
             ""
      ), 
      column(2,              
             # adding new page filter
             numericInput("page", "Page", 1, min = 1)
      ),
      column(12,
             dataTableOutput('table')
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$table <- renderDataTable(iris, options = list(pageLength = 5))

    # using new page filter
    observeEvent(input$page, {
      dataTableProxy("table") %>% selectPage(input$page)
    })
  }
)
```

Of course it would be nice to replace the actual DOM element. Then javascript would be the way to go. You could either find the element and overwrite the functionality or delete it and replace it. A good starting point would be here: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html. But i think it might be an overkill in terms of required time.